# Problems with Rake after switching to rvm and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rvm

So the crux of the problem, is I get the following error when running

```
rake -T

WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please Include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method SeenicServer::Application#task called at /home/grantismo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- parse_tree
```

So obviously I did, gem install ParseTree. 
Running `gem list -d ParseTree` produces:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

ParseTree (3.0.7)
    Author: Ryan Davis
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/parsetree
    Homepage: http://rubyforge.org/projects/parsetree/
    Installed at: /home/grantismo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180

    ParseTree is a C extension (using RubyInline) that extracts the
    parse tree for an entire class or a specific method and returns it
    as a s-expression (aka sexp) using ruby's arrays, strings, symbols,
    and integers
```

it looks like I'm using the correct rake

```
which rake

/home/grantismo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake
```

Most of the explanations I've read say to run `sudo gem install ParseTree`, but I don't understand why I should be installing with sudo if I'm managing gems through rvm.

Any ideas? I'm a unix noob, so it might be something simple. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure your `Gemfile` has a `gem 'ParseTree'` line in it, otherwise Rails won't load it (even if the system has it installed).

After adding the line, do a `bundle install`.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about bundle.